# need assist on bootstrap or something similar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

hey does a bootstrap like this exist where, in the content area ( the middle isnt spaces/margin/padding or what you call it, from the right and left sidebar

so its all connected

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/page-with-left-and-right-sidebar
https://www.bootply.com/101100

both of these sites have good bootstrap but i need no spaces if possible let me know thanks, i tried looking in the bootstrap itself but cant find what to remove/add, if some got one without bootstrap its okey too

i apprecitate all your time and hope you guys understand question

edit: i might done it wrong but i tried the

class row no gutters and no pad

but seems to still not work.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to remove the gutters? https://julienmelissas.com/no-gutter-column-trick-for-bootstrap/  which version of bootstrap?

Comment: bootstrap-3.3.7-dist

Comment: no one can be exact? :(

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've taken the 'no-gutter' class from this gist: https://gist.github.com/berfarah/b50c9e8872c9c44044dc I found it by searching google for "gutterless row boostrap css 3". "gutter" is a layout-term for the spaces between columns. Other frameworks could have a gutterless css-class built in.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a><a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed affix">
                <div class="well">
                    <ul class="nav ">
                        <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.well -->
            </div>
            <!--/sidebar-nav-fixed -->
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

                <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It
                    includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces
                    of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more »</a>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed pull-right affix">
                <div class="well">
                    <ul class="nav ">
                        <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.well -->
            </div>
            <!--/sidebar-nav-fixed -->
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
    </div>
    <!--/row-->

    <footer>
        <p>© Company 2012</p>
    </footer>
</div>
<!--/.fluid-container-->

<style>
body {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav-fixed {
    /*width:14%;*/
    width:100%
}

.no-gutter.row,
.no-gutter.container,
.no-gutter.container-fluid{
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.no-gutter>[class^="col-"]{
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it seems it still have space around :(

Comment: There shouldn't be any space between the columns on this example. Do you have other code in your project which could be effecting it?

Answer (score 0):

problem thanks for help, i used bootstrap 4.0.0 alpha 6

instead